# Is it possible to animate an SVG background on a DOM element with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have used SMIL to animate an SVG image, then used that image as the background for a DOM element (e.g., a `button`).

For example, this SVG image (http://mattstuehler.com/spinner.svg)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
  <g fill="none"  stroke="#1e81cc" stroke-width="4">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="18" stroke-opacity="0.3"/>
    <path d="M20,2 A18,18 0 0,1 38,20">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 20 20" to="360 20 20" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

However, now that SMIL is being deprecated, how would you do this with only CSS?

Thanks in advance!

```css
button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: url(http://mattstuehler.com/spinner.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello</button>
```

Comment: Chrome [stepped back](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/blink-dev/5o0yiO440LM/YGEJBsjUAwAJ) and won't deprecate SMIL anymore (at least not so soon)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:**

> Chrome have suspended deprecation of SMIL for now. More [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/blink-dev/5o0yiO440LM/YGEJBsjUAwAJ)

---

One way could be to use CSS animations. Animate the `path` element and fix the `transform-origin` at the center of the spinner.

Since we can have a [**`<style>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/style) tag within an SVG element, we **embed** this animation in the SVG itself.

**CSS Animation / SVG:**

```html
<svg height="40" viewbox="0 0 40 40" width="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    path {
      -webkit-animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
      animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
      transform-origin: 20px 20px;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
      }
    }
    @keyframes rotate {
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
      }
    }
  </style>
  <g fill="none" stroke="#1e81cc" stroke-width="4">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="18" stroke-opacity="0.3"></circle>
    <path d="M20,2 A18,18 0 0,1 38,20"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Using the above SVG as a background:**

```css
button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8j3gd6jfujxz2xg/spinner.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello</button>
```

Note:
 Some browsers may render animated SVGs as a static image **when used as a background**. Refers to both the CSS method and the SMIL in the question.
Works fine on Chrome/Opera and Firefox from version 51.

Comment: You can also use a pseudo-class ::before to show a static png image and rotate this pseudo-class using keyframes

Answer (score 2):

You can use any static PNG/WebP/JPG image as a background to a button's pseudo-class and then rotate it via CSS.

```css
@keyframes btn_rotate {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
} 

button::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: url(http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/spinner-icon-17.png);
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  animation: btn_rotate 2s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello</button>
```

Comment: thank you - this is an excellent answer. I wish I could credit two answers for being correct. As Ankith mentioned above - his answer may not have full browser support. Do you know how well supported this method is?

Comment: Pseudo selectors are supported very well cross browser. Also goes back till IE8, as far as I know. If its just the animation you are looking for, then this could definitely be the better way to do it.

Comment: If you are willing to make bigger changes on your code you can easily replace the pseudo-class for another div so you don't have to worry about pseudo-class support, which is pretty wide. For the css-animation support can check it here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation